# TypeError when form is submitted in django

Tags: django, forms, typeerror

I have a form at /item/3/sell_offer/4/
with action="add_post/"

I expect it go to /item/3/sell_offer/4/add_post

The relevant urlpatterns are

```
(r'^item/(?P<item_id>\d+)/sell_offer/(?P<sell_offer_id>\d+)/$', views.sell_offer_page),
(r'^item/(?P<item_id>\d+)/sell_offer/(?P<sell_offer_id>\d+)/add_post/$', views.sell_offer_add_post),
```

and the view looks like..

```
def sell_offer_add_post(request, item_id, sell_offer_id):
    p = request.POST

    if p.has_key("body") and p["body"]:
        post = SellOfferPost(sell_offer=SellOfferPost.objects.get(pk=sell_offer_id))
        form = SellOfferPostForm(p, instance=post)
        post = form.save()
        post.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('views.sell_offer_page', args=[item_id, sell_offer_id]))
```

I think post action doesn't actually find it's way to the view.
Below is the error message

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://......:8000/item/1/sell_offer/4/add_post/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
sell_offer_add_post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'item_id'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 111
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you haven't called some other view `sell_offer_add_post()` further down.

Comment: To expand on this... @Eugene- If you have DEBUG=True in your settings.py, you should be getting a very robust traceback page that shows you exactly what bit of code this is occurring in, allow you to verify its not a duplicate view with a different signature.

Comment: Umm I don't have any other sell_offer_add_post function. @jdi: The error output I posted is generated with DEBUG=True, I pasted only relavant informations.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your view signature to this:

```
def sell_offer_add_post(request, item_id=None, sell_offer_id=None):
```

I haven't tested but if I remember right, when you use named capture groups in your URL I think django tries to pass named keywords. You need to check the values in the view.